# How can I make a break point at the specific [nsstring release] without subclassing NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, nsstring

Can I make a break point at the specific NSString object's release message?

for example:

```
if (phoneNumber) [phoneNumber release];
phoneNumber = [newPhone retain];
```

then, I want to set a break point at the phoneNumber's release method, and I don't want to subclass NSString to set a break point at the release method.

is it possible? I think it is possible, and I'm still googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the specific question, you would use a conditional breakpoint.  Create a global variable, assign the string you want to break on into that global variable, set a breakpoint on -release, then use the conditional breakpoint to break when needed.

But that is all [most likely] a complete waste of time.    As a guess, I'm betting you are trying to track down a retain/release problem?  ... an over-release, perchance?

In any case, Instruments will quite conveniently track all retain/releases of all objects. It will also detect over-releases.   Other tools can easily be used to track over-retains.

Having to track the release of a particular string object is generally only something you do out of desperation, having exhausted the vast variety of other tools.